# Which to store: miles or kilometers?

Tags: database-design, l10n

My app is launching to a US audience first, but I want to internationalize the database schema for future expansion. Obviously I will convert between the two units as necessary regardless, but are there any benefits to storing one or the other in the database? My initial thought is that it might be helpful to store kilometers since miles are used by less countries worldwide, so long-term, I will be doing less conversions overall. But in the short-term, while the app is still US-only, I will be converting units every time I access the database.

Comment: It's likely the UI will be doing any conversion or rounding so the additional miles/ kilometer calculation is moot.  Pick one and stick with it.  You will want the same display algorithm for all users, so even those who adopt the base unit will have a conversion factor of x1. I'd suggest whichever your developers are familiar with, just to make it easy on them.  Use the unit in column names so it is explicit e.g. DistanceToPizza_km. Be aware you may not get exactly the same value in as you get out, due to rounding, so the application has to be resilient to this.

Comment: Why do you want to make less conversions?

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend storing everything in Planck Lengths.  That way you get the most accuracy possible.

The Planck length, is the unit of length approximately 1.6 * 10^-35 metres. It is in the system of units known as Planck units. The Planck length is deemed "natural" because it can be defined from three fundamental physical constants: the speed of light, Planck's constant, and the gravitational constant. Max Planck was the first to propose the Planck length, a base unit in a system of measurement he called "natural units". Although quantum mechanics and general relativity were unknown when Planck proposed his natural units, it later became clear that at a distance equal to the Planck length, gravity begins to display quantum effects, whose understanding would require a theory of quantum gravity.

Meter lengths are an easy conversion of "x" meters divided by 1.6e+35.

Of course, you going to need a fairly large data type to store your measurements.

All kidding aside, why not store the unit-of-measurement with the actual measurement (in a separate column of course, probably as a foreign key).  This way when you are displaying the measurement you do not need to convert it at all.  Simply display the measurement, along with the unit of measure.  The only time you'll need to convert the measurement is if you want to compare it to other measurements in a *different unit*.

Comment: The down side of storing uom being you need an n^2 array of conversion factors, where n = number of stored units + number of user display units. Depending on how diverse you think your user base will become this may complicate caching and the UI.

Comment: -1 I think that does not make sense. Adding the unit make things more complicate (e.g. if you compare or subtract values). The unit can be a user specific value. For saving the unit with the length value there must be a special reason and such reason I cannot find in the description of the OP.

Comment: I don't agree, obviously.  Storing the UoM makes sense for a ton of real-world scenarios, and no matter how the OP decides to store the measurements, it will necessitate some kind of conversion.

Comment: But what is the advantage of storing the unit? If you propose to change the implementation there should be compelling reasons to do so.

Comment: Storing the unit means the interface never has to assume the unit of measure, while simultaneously allowing the user flexibility in specifying the unit they are comfortable with.  If you aren't comparing values, you can display/summarize/report far more easily, without needing to perform conversions.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with **m** unit and **int** datatype, as meters are SI unit and int should be the fastest and the most memory effective.